# Wordpress featured image as full width-image: achieved with additional CSS

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

...running wordpress Version 5.9.2 : i was wondering if there’s an easy way to customize the CSS for the featured image to appear with full width. At the moment the image has a huge margin - and is not full width as it appears on the page (see below) - https://www.job-starter.com/

i tried to get this to work with this WordPress theme by including some code into the custom CSS option - see below;

what is aimed:  How can I set the featured images to a full width:

i tried the following code snippets in the option additional CSS:

```
FIGURE.block-image IMG {
max-width: 320px;
height: auto;
}


#2
FIGURE.block-image IMG {
max-width: 320px;
height: auto;
}

or

.block-image IMG {
width: 600px;
height: auto;
}
```

see the examination of the page:

Update: Hello dear @Howard E many thanks for the quick reply. Great to hear from you. I am so glad that you hepled me. Its awesome: i am running the theme called jobify: see the demo page: - Here is the live site - with the demo of this theme:

- https://2709.getwpt.tech/  and besides here:
  https://jobify-demos.astoundify.com/extended/

**Question**: Can we get the look and feel of the theme like it is shown on the demo-pages? That would  be great. Many thanks in advance. - You saved my day.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a little vague.  If you want to make the first `wp-block-image` on every page 100% width, you can do this.  But it will work on every page.

You need to understand better how to scope your css.

But this should work.

```
article .wp-block-image:first-of-type img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Hello dear @Howard E many thanks for the quick reply. Great to hear from you.  I am so glad that you hepled me. Its awesome: i am running the theme called jobify: see the demo page: - Here is the live site - with the demo of this theme:  

https://2709.getwpt.tech/  and besides here:  https://jobify-demos.astoundify.com/extended/
 
Question: Can we get the look and feel of the theme like it is shown on the demo-pages? That would  be great. Many thanks in advance. - You saved my day.